# Select ID Column if another column contains 2 Values by Date Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table whose structure is as follows:

[image: ID Table]

I want to only select the ID which contains following 2 Descriptions (Reported, Resolved) However, the reported must come before Resolved by date.

So in the above table example I should get ID **1** when I run the query

Comment: What have you tried so far, why didn't it work? Could the reported Date be on the same date as the Resolved date?

Comment: Also, those dates appear incomplete, there's no year. How do you know that 5-Feb is not after 6-Feb? Without the year, this would be very troublesome if you had dates like `30-Dec` and `02-Jan` or where the time period extends more than a year.

Comment: @Larnu the reported date and resolved date can be on the same day, however, the date column does contain time too as follows: 2017-06-02 20:10:57.847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having max(case when description ='Reported' then date end) < max(case when description = 'Resolved' then date end)
```

The `HAVING` clause will return `TRUE` only if both descriptions exist for the same id and the inequality is satisfied. 
If any of them is missing the result will be `NULL` and the `id` will be filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select id
from table t
group by id
where Descriptions in ('Reported', 'Resolved') 
having count(*) = 2 and
       max(case when Descriptions = 'Reported' then date end) < 
       max(case when Descriptions = 'Resolved' then date end);
```

Comment: thank you this one also worked, count clause limited it to only ids where only 2 instances of the condition existed. Nevertheless good solution for other purposes.